# HTML checkbox select one at a time per group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've been trying some code to be able to check 1 checkbox at a time, but I also want to be able to check 1 box at a time in another group at the same time ( they work together )

This is the code I've tried so far:

**HTML**

Checkbox group1

```
                <div class="modal-body">
                Status to change:
                <br><br>
                <label for=".checkboxSanction">Sanction Status
                    <input type="checkbox" name="statusbox" value="Sanction Status" class="checkboxSanction">
                </label><br>
                <label for=".checkboxPep">Pep Status
                    <input type="checkbox" name="statusbox" value="PEP Status" class="checkboxPep">
                </label><br>
                <label for=".checkboxUnderage">Underage Status
                    <input type="checkbox" name="statusbox" value="Underage Status" class="checkboxUnderage">
                </label><br><br>
                Change status to:
```

Checkbox group2

```
                <label for=".checkboxInvestigating">Investigating
                    <input type="checkbox" name="valuebox" value="2" class="checkboxInvestigating">
                </label></br>
                <label for=".checkboxClosed">Closed
                    <input type="checkbox" name="valuebox" value="10" class="checkboxClosed">
                </label>
            </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

The problem here is that I can only check 1 box at a time, and that goes for all of the checkboxes ( as in both groups ) - *I want to be able to check 1 per group.*

Does anyone have an idea of how do solve this issue? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons?

Comment: @AdamAzad I want the users to be able to uncheck the buttons aswell

Comment: you can do that (uncheck the buttons) with radiobutton too

Comment: @Dr Cox: Yes but you want to select at least one option in every group. So Radio button is useful to you.

Comment: @YoYo I think that using uncheckable radio buttons is not the way you want to go in webdesign. When I am seeing radio buttons, I usually am sure that I won't be able to uncheck them, as that is their common behaviour. Don't cause confusion that does not have to happen

Comment: @Marv : before you further confuse all Refer this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/24vft2of/2/

Comment: @YoYo it is not about me confusing people, but about using radiobuttons and checkboxes what they are made for. Radiobuttons are not supposed to be unchecked, there shall always be one in a group that is checked. That is a fact that is in the mind of most of your users when they are visiting your website, therefore they are not going to expect that they can uncheck it. If you want your users to know that they can uncheck, you want to use checkboxes, as that is what they are made for.

Comment: @Marv :it depends on you how you use it as per requirement .. its not like elements are booked to do appropiate task only .I dont want to argue more please

Comment: @YoYo but I really like to argue. You are correct, elements are not bound to certain tasks, but if you are building a UI and want it to be as user friendly as possible, you want to use the elements just like everyone is used to use them. Real life example: Planes are made for flying. If you tell your friends "Lets travel to xyz by plane" they are expecting to fly there. They will be amazed that you can stay on the ground and basically drive to your destination with the plane, but will be confused nevertheless as that was not their first thought on it.

Comment: @YoYo building websites is all about making it as easy to use as possible for your user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    $("input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr('name')+"']").not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Same concept as your example just a little more concise.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb7oyzaf/2/)

**EDIT:** I've just properly checked your example and it works fine too see here

[JSFiddle for your code](https://jsfiddle.net/cb7oyzaf/1/)

Comment: hmm, it works fine on your fiddle but not in my application, does the modal dialog have anything to do with that?

Comment: I don't see why that would interfere, is it not working at all or is it not letting you select one per group? Check the console for any other errors. You could also make your input:checkbox selector that you're attaching the click handler to more precise.

Comment: It's the same problem when trying it in the app, I can't select one per group

Comment: I don't remember what was wrong, but this worked after some modifications in the app, I'll accept your answer because that's what I went on using for this, thank you good sir! :)

Comment: No worries, sounds like something else had interfered. Good work